# Toggle div on click with mulitple div's

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-ui

I want to show/hide multiple divs with same name

```
<div class="slide"><button>Click Here</button></div>
<div class="slideChild"></div>
<div class="slideChild"></div>
<div class="slideChild"></div>
<div class="slideChild"></div>


<div class="some content">ABC</div>

<div class="slide"><button>Click Here</button></div>
<div class="slideChild"></div>
<div class="slideChild"></div>
<div class="slideChild"></div>
<div class="slideChild"></div>
```

Above is the sample text i can't change the class strucutre or append any classes so any idea regarding this issues.

I know we can use jquery toggle when button event fired but it's slideup all div's so i have to use other closest or something.

```
  $("body").on("click","button",function(){
         $('.slideChild').toggle();
  });
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more of the issue you're having? You can hide them all with the jquery code posted, but you're saying it doesn't work as you expect? why

Comment: when i press button it will only slideup 4 slideChild div near that div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery's [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$( ".slideChild" ).toggle();
```

Comment: It will toggle both div's i want only closest div's not after ABC text

Comment: what do you mean by closest div? closest to what?

Comment: Only four Slidechild div  which are nearest to that div.

Comment: Then change the name of either the top or the bottom one. Or you can't change it?

Comment: i can't change it. it comes from plugin.

Comment: what plugin did you used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137125/discussion-between-rahul-gandhrokiya-and-carl-jan).

Comment: it's from composite product plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery

```
$('.slideone button').click(function(){
    $(".slideChild").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps.

Here's a half working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pqmg1Loq/

If you click on the button after `ABC` they will disappear. I used the `~` selector, which means "all sibling selectors after this one", similar to the "+" but selecting all of them.

The problem with the button before the `ABC` is that the same approach will hide all the elements, since all of them are following it.

A solution would be, when clicked on the first button, create an array with all the `.slideChild` elements, then loop through it and hide the elements *until* you find the `.some.content` element.

Hope that helps.

Comment: but parent class are same  is not like slide and slideOne it's only slide.

Comment: They were not the same in your original example, you edited it :p

Comment: Yes i see the code and find that there is one issues so i changed the code as per my functionality i have to create on my project.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way what is , you have to  put all of slidechild class into the slideone class div which are close to slideone class div.

```
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <div class="slideOne"><button>Click Here</button>
<div class="slideChild">A</div>
<div class="slideChild">B</div>
<div class="slideChild">C</div>
<div class="slideChild">D</div>

</div>


<div class="some content">ABC</div>

<div class="slide"><button>Click Here</button>
<div class="slideChild" id="a">E</div>
<div class="slideChild">F</div>
<div class="slideChild">G</div>
<div class="slideChild">H</div>
</div>

<script>
 $(document).on("click","button",function(){
     var parendDIv=$(this).parent('div').attr('class');
     $("."+parendDIv+">.slideChild").toggle();


  });  
</script>
```

Comment: changing class name not possible or conflict with other area of development.

Comment: Sorry you didn't get me. I didn't say to chage the class name .You just see that where is the end of slideone class div of my comment  as well as see the js code. I hope you got my point. :)